# Optimizing daily data storage in a relational db

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Update: There was a comment that the question was not clear, that I made a leap of logic claiming that I would have 118 billion rows. I have edited the text below to clarify things. See the italicized text below

I have been struggling with this for a while now, have even gone down a few paths, but I turn now to the community for ideas. First, the problem — Store six daily variables for ~ 25 years for cells in a grid.

- Number of vars = 6
- Number of cells ~ 13 million
- Number of days ~ 9125 (25 * 365)

Optimize the store for two different kinds of queries —

Query one: Retrieve the value of a single var for all or a portion of the cells for a single day. This is analogous to an image where every pixel is the value of a single var.

Query two: Retrieve values for all the days or a duration of days for a single var for a single cell. This is like grabbing a column out of a table in which each row holds all the vars for a single day.

So, I set about designing the db. A single table *where every row is one day's values for one cell* would like so

```
CREATE TABLE d (
    yr      SMALLINT,
    yday    SMALLINT,
    a       SMALLINT,
    b       SMALLINT,
    d       SMALLINT,
    e       SMALLINT,
    f       SMALLINT,
    g       SMALLINT,
    cell_id INTEGER
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
)
```

The data would look like so

```
yr      yday    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   cell_id
----------------------------------------------------
1980    1       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
1980    2       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
1980    3       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
..
1980    365     x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
...
1981    1       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
1981    2       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
1981    3       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
..
1981    365     x   x   x   x   x   x   x   1
```

The problem: The above table would have 13 m * 9125 rows ~ 118 billion rows. Huge indexes, slow queries, major issues loading the data, etc.

So, I partitioned the table into years like so

```
CREATE TABLE d_<yyyy> (
    CHECK ( yr = <yyyy> )
) INHERITS (d)
```

Hmmm... still no satisfaction. I ended up with 1 + 25 tables, but each of the year tables now had ~ 4.75 billion rows, and the queries were still very slow.

So, I partitioned it all by years and days like so

```
CREATE TABLE d_<yyyy>_<yday> (
    CHECK ( yr = <yyyy> AND yday = <yday> )
) INHERITS (d)
```

Each table now has 13 million rows, and is reasonably fast (although still not satisfactorily fast), but now I have 9K tables. That has its own problems. I can't query the master table anymore as Pg tries to lock all the tables and runs out of memory. Additionally, I can't anymore conduct query two above. I could do something like

```
SELECT a FROM d_1980_1 WHERE cell_id = 1 
UNION 
SELECT a FROM d_1980_2 WHERE cell_id = 1 
UNION 
SELECT a FROM d_1980_3 WHERE cell_id = 1 
UNION 
SELECT a FROM d_1980_4 WHERE cell_id = 1 
UNION 
...
```

But the above is hardly optimal.

Any suggestions, ideas, brainstorms would be appreciated. Perhaps Pg, or even a RDBMS, is not the right tool for this problem, in which case, suggestion for alternatives would be welcome as well.

Comment: Dare i say it, but we might actually need some more detail. i have read your question four times and still am at a loss as to what you're trying to accomplish or how you could end up with a table with billions of rows. Please review and revise your question. i suspect that you're making a few leaps in logic and maybe losing people. this does sound interesting though. (Little bit of formatting helped actually.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kinds of operations you want to be able to perform on the data?

Comment: Why do you want to store them in a database?  If you have only one table with a simple structure, and are only performing simple queries, why not just stick them in a large file.

Comment: How are the cells in your grid structured? Could that grid of cells be represented by a table?

Comment: why do I want to store the data in a database? Well, for simplicity and flexibility of querying, especially when different kinds of queries are required (note my query one and query two).

Of course, I am not sure if an RDBMS is the right solution, and am trying to make that decision.

Comment: @punkish you wrote: "I can't query the master table anymore as Pg tries to lock all the tables and runs out of memory."  Really?  Are you sure Postgres is taking table locks when answering read-only SELECTs like your queries #1 and #2?

Comment: @Dan LaRocque: SELECT does lock with ACCESS SHARE but I'm surprised th e lock itself would cause it to run out of memory.

Comment: @punkis: what is a reason time expectation for these queries?  What kind of hardware are you attempting to run these on?

Comment: @rfusca thanks for the tip! now i see this fact was in plain sight: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: @rfusca: I am assuming that Pg tries to lock 9000 odd tables, and runs out of memory. I forget the exact error, but the error very clearly says that it is out of memory, and that I could change some shared memory settings to try and run the query.

Comment: @rfusca: Right now I am testing this on a dual Xeon 3 GHz Xserve with 12 GB RAM. The PGDATA directory is located on an attached RAID that is configured as RAID5. Reasonable time for a query would be under 500 ms, although ultimately I would love to have the query be done under 250 ms.

Comment: @punkish RAID levels aren't my specialty, but I know RAID 10 is recommeded over 5.  For answers on tuning a setup like this, I'd really recommend posting to the PG  performance mailing list.

Comment: @punkish Postgres' Tom Lane has said before that the current partitioning setup isn't really designed to scale past a couple of dozen partitions currently.  I believe its "on the list" to fix in a future release though.

Comment: Two questions:  (1) You say "cells in a grid" and then give an approximate figure of 13 million cells.  Is this the result of an X times Y = approx 13 million cells calcuation?  That is, is there a natural (X,Y) "coordinate" for each cell_id?  (2) The data types for the six vars are smallint.  Does the *actual* range of values for each one cover the entire smallint? I understand that smallint is the smallest integer type PostgreSQL has, but I'm curious what the actual min and max of each of those fields are...

Comment: "@Matthew Wood" - Yes, 13 million = X * Y, and each cell has a unique x,y "coordinate." The data type are SMALLINT in Pg because, as you rightly noted, Pg's smallest datatype is SMALLINT. The actual range of the values is actually 8-bits, that is, between 0 and 255.

Actually, I asked this question on the Pg list, and although I am still not 100% so convinced, I am coming to the conclusion that Pg is perhaps not the right solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to massive indexing, or duplication of data, I think it will be difficult to find a single schema design, which is optimal for both of your queries.

By clustering your data by either date or sensor, retrieval by one of these conditions can be made to run fast, but not both at the same time.

Assuming that access by date is the most important, you could layout your table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE d (
    day      DATE,
    a       SMALLINT[],
    b       SMALLINT[],
    ...
);
```

Observe that there is now only one row per day, and that cell fields have become arrays, where each cell will have its own index. In case the cell numbering is not zero-based, a table could be fitted with the mapping from cell ids to array indexes.

Query 1,

> Retrieve the value of a single var for
>   all or a portion of the cells for a
>   single day.

is accomplished by, for example,

```
SELECT a FROM d WHERE day = '1981-01-01'
```

Query 2,

> Retrieve values for all the days or a duration of days for a single var for a single cell.

will be of the form

```
SELECT a[1000] FROM d WHERE day BETWEEN '1981' AND '1982'
```

I believe large arrays in PostgreSQL are accessed without actually loading the whole data structure. I know BLOBs are. If that is the case, this solution may be fast enough for you. Otherwise I would suggest making another view of the data, which optimizes access by cell.